# What is the latest official document that describes simplification of radicals?

Tags: history, traditional-vs-simplified

The document 《漢字簡化方案》 was published in 1956 by [State Council of the People's Republic of China](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q59261) and it lists the simplification of some radicals in page 10 (see screenshot below). [Here's the document](https://archive.org/details/hanzi_jianhua_fangan_1956_20220420) in archive.org.

[image]

The document 《简化字总表》 was published in 1986 by [National Language Commission](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10926073) and it lists simplified characters along with their traditional counterpart from page 25 to page 34 (see screenshot of a sample page below). Characters are grouped by radicals, so it is possible to determine the simplification of each radical. [Here's the document](https://archive.org/details/jianhuazi_1986_old_20200823) in archive.org.

[image]

I want to know if besides those publications, any other public institution from China has published a document with updated information on the simplification of radicals.

I am asking this question because I want to create an infographic that summarizes the simplification of each radical for convenience, so I want to use the latest official information (i.e. avoid using obsolete information.)

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer allowed to simplify an obscure character by simplifying its individual components. Therefore, the "simplification of components" table you see in older documents is no longer produced.

https://www.gov.cn/govweb/zwhd/2009-08/19/content_1396490.htm

> 《通用规范汉字表》以外的字，根据国务院1986年“今后，对汉字的简化应持谨慎态度，使汉字的形体在一个时期内保持相对稳定”的指示精神，不再类推简化；个别领域确需类推简化的，需报国家语言文字工作主管部门批准。